# How can an element inside an iframe capture a key event?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, dom-events

I have a canvas element in a simple html document with an attached `keydown` and `keyup` listener. This works correctly when I load the document in the browser and start pressing the keys. However, if I load the document in an iframe, nothing happens when I press the keys. It seems the key events never enter the iframe or the document inside the iframe. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: What element were you focused on when pressing keys? iFrames can only listen to events in themselves.

Comment: Code? Example? http://jsfiddle.net/?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in this question. Setting the focus on the document inside the iframe solves the problem

[Setting focus to iframe contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369026/setting-focus-to-iframe-contents)

Answer (score 0):

I found subscribing the event to window.top worked for me, as my game was several iframes deep.