# Set focus on iframe in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, iframe, designmode

I have an iframe (`id: 'chat'`) with `designMode='on'` in Chrome.

On Enter keypress event I call the function `send()`, which takes the iframe contents and writes it to a socket. My problem is that when clearing the iframe, I lose focus.

How to do I set the focus so I can continue to type text in the iframe?

```
function send(){
    var $iframe = $('#chat');
    var text = $iframe.contents().text() + "\n";  

    socket.send(text);

    // When this is done, the focus is lost
    // If commented, the focus will not be lost
    $iframe.contents().find('body').empty();

    // My different failed attempts to regain the focus
    //$iframe.focus();
    //$iframe.contents().focus();
    //$iframe.contents().find('body').focus();
    //$iframe.contents().find('body').parent().focus();
    //$iframe[0].contentWindow.focus();

    // I've also tried all the above with timers
    //setTimeout( function(){ $('#chat').contents().focus(); }, 100);
}
```

I've tried many of the solutions on other questions, but none seems to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to first set focus on the body and then create a `Range`.

```
var win = iframe.contentWindow;
var range = win.document.createRange();
range.setStart(win.document.body, 0);
range.setEnd(win.document.body, 0);
win.document.body.focus();
win.getSelection().addRange(range);
```

Comment: Clearly that was the trick! It works. That made my day! .. Now I only have a trailing new line from the event still lingering. But atleast I have my focus!

Answer (score 2):

This question has been [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369026/setting-focus-to-iframe-contents)

Basically, if you are not refreshing the iframe you could use:

```
$iframe[0].contentWindow.focus();
```

Note that I'm grabbing the underlying iframe DOM object.

Comment: I just tried that code as well. Unfortunately I still won't get the focus back. (I edited the question adding your suggestion)

Comment: What if you do that in a setTimeout to give the iframe a bit of time to start inflating?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried below solution it works in all browser (IE/Chrome/Firefox)

Context: I want to focus the iframe all the time.

```
    function IFocus() {
        var iframe = $("#iframeId")[0];
        iframe.contentWindow.focus();
    };
    window.setInterval(IFocus, 300);
```

Hope it helps, if any one in need...

Answer (score 0):

I tested this solution with Chrome.   I originally posted it in [Setting focus to iframe contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369026/setting-focus-to-iframe-contents).

Here is code to create an iframe using jQuery, append it to the document, poll it until it is loaded, then focus it.   This is better than setting an arbitrary timeout which may or may not work depending on how long the iframe takes to load.

```
var jqueryIframe = $('<iframe>', {
    src: "http://example.com"
}),
focusWhenReady = function(){
    var iframe = jqueryIframe[0],
    doc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
    if (doc.readyState == "complete") {
        iframe.contentWindow.focus();
    } else {
        setTimeout(focusWhenReady, 100)
    }
}
$(document).append(jqueryIframe);
setTimeout(focusWhenReady, 10);
```

The code for detecting when the iframe is loaded was adapted from [Biranchi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/97651/biranchi)'s answer to [How to check if iframe is loaded or it has a content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249680/how-to-check-if-iframe-is-loaded-or-it-has-a-content)