# How to set focus on an iframe that is cross-domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, iframe, cross-domain

Similar to the posts below:

1. [Set focus on iframe in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111003/set-focus-on-iframe-in-chrome)
2. [Setting focus to iframe contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369026/setting-focus-to-iframe-contents)

From the root/parent I want to be able to pass focus to the iframe.

Anything that may be in focus in the iframe is fine.

```
iframe.contentWindow.focus();
```

However, the iframe.contentWindow is not accessible because its a cross-origin frame.

Comment: You can not access it

Comment: If you don't control the domain in the iframe, then you cannot do it. If you do control both domains, then you could communicate between the two using [Window.postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage). This way you could send a message to the page in iframe and then set the focus in the iframe itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the answer is: not possible.

If there is a script running in the iframe you can directly call focus from there.