# Set focus to the middle of the Iframe in html5

Tags: html, focus

I am showing an external webpage inside an `iframe` and I want to set focus directly to the content of the webpage, the content is at the middle of the web page.

How can I achieve that?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean to set focus inside the iframe?

Comment: Yes..I want to set focus inside the iframe

Comment: Check it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369026/setting-focus-to-iframe-contents

Answer (score 1):

If the page is on another domain you'll run into XSS (cross-site-scripting) issues and barriers put up by the browsers to avoid malicious manipulations!

If you are serving the page yourself you can do this:

**inner.html**:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head><title>the iframe</title></head><body>
Hello World!<br/>
This is where we start to select something ..<br/>
.. right here: <input type="text" id="toBeSelected" size="12" value="this is to be selected" onfocus="this.select()"/><br/>
</body>
</html>
```

**outer.html**:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head><title>fun with IFRAME</title></head><body>
<ol type="i">
<li>wait for loading..</li>
<li>..<a href="#" id="andThen" style="display: none;" onclick="setFocus(); return false;">set focus</a></li>
<li>..see the effect.</li>
</ol>
<iframe id="theIFRAME" width="500" height="500" frameborder="1" data-src="inner.html" style="margin: 1em auto 0;">NO IFRAME support</iframe>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--

function setFocus(){
    var domIFRAME = document.getElementById('theIFRAME'), 
        docIFRAME = domIFRAME ? ( domIFRAME.contentDocument || domIFRAME.contentWindow.document ) : null;
    if( docIFRAME ) docIFRAME.getElementById('toBeSelected').focus(); else console.log("oups!");
}

function handleIframeContent(){
    console.log("okay, it has loaded.");
    document.getElementById('andThen').style.display = 'inline';
}

var domIFRAME = document.getElementById('theIFRAME');
domIFRAME.onload = handleIframeContent;
domIFRAME.src = domIFRAME.getAttribute('data-src');
// --></script>
</body>
```

Of course, you can do the `.focus()` bit inside the `handleIframeContent()`, the demo just wants to give you time to appreciate it is actually not the default state of the page inside the IFRAME.

HTH