# How to have a URL With a Query String and focus on Element inside an iframe

Tags: html, url, iframe

In the URL, you can focus on a particular element by appending a '#' and its id. For example:

http://stackoverflow.com?#footer

The code above will auto-focus you to the element with the id "footer". If this page was inside an iframe, it will not set focus on the element.

Any suggestions how to set focus in iframe to the element with selected id?

Comment: is it on your domain?

Comment: yes, I cannot set focus on my page that is open in iframe

Comment: have a look at this, it may offer some solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369026/setting-focus-to-iframe-contents