# How to implement 'Skip to Content' between two frames

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, vbscript, accessibility

I am working on a website using frames. The top frame holds the menu items and the bottom frame holds the main content.

How can I href to main frame content section?

Comment: Code would be super helpful here. What have you tried?

Comment: You shouldn't use frames.

Answer (score 0):

In 2017, no one uses `frame`.

But if you really want to, you can use the `name` attribute specified for your bottom frame

```
<frame src="mypage.html" name="bottom" />
```

in the `target` attribute of your link:

```
<a href="mypage.html" target="bottom">Skip to content</a>
```

Thanks, for the nostalgia.

Answer (score -1):

Using `frameset` and `frame` elements is really old-fashioned now. (The most prominent examples are probably the [Java API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/), and any other Java documentation generated using [Javadoc](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-jsp-135444.html), and the [Eclipse documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp).) However, if you have a frameset containing one frame for navigation and one frame for the main content, here is what you should do.

First, give each `frame` element both a `name` and a `title`. The `title` is for assistive technologies, especially screen readers. See the example below.

```
<frameset cols="15%, *">
  <frame src="navigation.html" name="navigation" title="Navigation Bar" />
  <frame src="main.html" name="maincontent" title="Main Content" />
  <noframes>
    <p>Go to the <a href="noframe.html">version without frames</a>.</p>
  </noframes>
</frameset>
```

Second, make sure the user can navigate between the frames. Firefox and several other browsers allow the user to navigate to the next frame by pressing `F6` and to the previous frame by pressing `Shift`+ `F6`, but Google Chrome does not appear to have a keyboard shortcut for this (see [Chrome keyboard shortcuts](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en) in Google Chrome Help). (You would need to add the [Vimium extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vimium/dbepggeogbaibhgnhhndojpepiihcmeb/details) to have a shortcut for frame nagivation. Frame navigation in Chrome using just a keyboard is a nightmare.) So you would probably need a script that sets the focus to the `maincontent` frame after clicking a link in the `navigation` frame. See the question [Setting focus to iframe contents](https://stackoverflow.com/q/369026/6002174) for something related.

Alternative solution: stop using frames.