# Focus on iframe every time I click on specific button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to focus on iframe every time I click on `<button class="bold" >bold</button>`

But It Only Works one time

Here is my code :

**JavaScript** :

```
function iFrameStart() {
    iframe.document.designMode="On";
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",iFrameStart,false);
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".bold").click(function () {
       iframe.document.execCommand('bold',false,null);
       document.getElementById("iframe").focus();
    });
});
```

**HTML** :

```html
<div class="container">
    <h1>Editor Demo</h1>
    <div class="button-wrapper">
        <button class="bold">B</button>
    </div>
    <label><textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea></label>
    <iframe id="iframe" name="iframe" ></iframe>

</div>
```

Comment: Why not use css? There is focus selector. [W3school](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_focus.asp)

Comment: @MTBthePRO they are trying to apply focus to the iframe, not stylize it based upon being focused.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369026/setting-focus-to-iframe-contents

Comment: Does it blur and not focus again? or it just stays focused?

Comment: the first time works ok but when I click on the button again it won't focus at all

Comment: @imvain2 I've already tried that not working :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it is a solution for you.

```
$('#iframe').contents().find('html').focus();
```

And vanilla js

```
const frame = document.querySelector('#iframe').contentWindow;
frame.document.querySelector('body').focus();
```