# How to set focus on input on the iframe

Tags: javascript, php, iframe

Can someone help me to keep the focus on the input in the iframe that embeds from other page. I want to use it to input key to control the motor dc to my IoT project. In the original page autofocus just work fine, but on the main page when i wanna enter the value you have to click it first and the autofocus just not work.

My iframe script just like this

```
<iframe name="foo" id="foo" width="280" height="100px" frameborder="0" src="http://blabla" autofocus></iframe>
```

And in blabla page is only have one usually input like

```
<input type='text' name='foo' id='foo' size='10' onkeydown='myFunction(event)' autofocus>
```

i use Version 77.0.3865.90 Google chrome
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting focus to iframe contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369026/setting-focus-to-iframe-contents)

Comment: i already see that and try few of that but seems not work. i use Version 77.0.3865.90 Google chrome