# How to set focus for #document in iframe using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, focus

How to set focus to #document inside an iframe using javascript ?

[image]

Tried the below code but not working

```
  document.getElementById('iframe').focus()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting focus to iframe contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369026/setting-focus-to-iframe-contents)

Comment: No.I'm still not getting focus. I specifically want to focus on the document body 

this.AppLaunchEl.contentWindow.document.body.focus()

i have also tried 

this.AppLaunchEl.contentWindow.document.focus()

Comment: But did you wait for the page to reload $(document).ready(// your functions) @KadeejaBai

Comment: I cant use jQuery methods in this case so I haven't checked it. I have tried waiting for a while after the iframe is loaded

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
  var iframe = document.getElementById("myFrame");
  var elmnt = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementById("elementId");
  elmnt.focus();
```

Comment: The element body will be different each time so cant use it.