# How to move IFrame scrollbars from another IFrame

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I recently ran into a problem where I have an Index page in which there are 3 IFrames.

1th IFrame : Views the photo (photo name)

2th IFrame : A simple list of all links (list name)

3th IFrame : Views the a big photo (pag name)

```
-Index.htm


<table border="0" align="center" height=100% width="100%" height=150  >
  <tr>
   <td valign="top" width=300 align=center bgcolor=#aaaaaa> 
    <iframe frameBorder="1" width=300 height=300 id="photo" name="photo" src=""></iframe>
    <iframe frameBorder="0" width=300 name="list" height=300 src="list.htm"></iframe> <p>
  </td>
  <td valign="top" colspan="2">
    <iframe frameBorder="0" id="pag" name="pag" src="pag.htm" width=100% height=100%>
    </iframe>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>

-List.htm

<script type="text/javascript">

function movePic() {

//  works but only on current window 
//  window.scrollTo(0,170);
// not even that works
// window.parent.document.getElementById("pag").focus();
      }

</script>

<body topmargin=0 bgcolor="#ffffff" link="#0000FF" text="#000000" alink="#FF0000" vlink="#FF00FF">
<a href="pic/aa27.jpg" target="photo" onclick="movePic()">Requested Point</a>
```

-Pag.htm

A big photo which needs to be moved throughout scrollbars to a certain point.

I tried in many ways, but I can't from the 2th IFrame (list name) pass its focus to the 3th IFrame (map name)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting focus to iframe contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369026/setting-focus-to-iframe-contents)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @IT goldman it is possible to accomplish this without JQuery.